# Merging 2 .csv files in Pandas with specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, documentation

I am starting out learning about python and I wanted to merge 2 data rich .csv files. Can anyone help.

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
csv1.str.lower()
csv1.head()
print(csv1.shape)
csv2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
csv2.head()
print(csv2.shape)
print (csv1)
```

I can't go further from this code. I am not experienced as much. Can anyone give me a sample code.

The data is here. I have to merge with reference to columns '2' and '3' in 1.csv and '2A' and '3A' in 2.csv.

I know I have to use `merge` function with `how = 'inner'` and I can't figure out the `on = ???`

[The 2 data sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srSPo.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have different names of columns that you want to merge on, use arguments `left_on` and `right_on` instead of `on`.

So the answer is something like this:

```
csv1.merge(csv2, how='inner', left_on=['2', '3'], right_on=['2A', '3A'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = pd.merge(csv1, csv2,  how='left', left_on=['2','3'], right_on = ['2A','3A'])
```

left join returns all records from left and matching records from right table.
If you only want matching records, use "inner join".

Comment: I see. That would definitely be a better way to merge those data. So, 'inner join' can overwrite data too?